# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View:

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to use data 2 query in 1 view but

> Error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

```
 (View:
     public function adtranspc(Request $request)
        {
          $writter = Writter::all();
             $processmaster = DB::table('rocessmaster')
             ->where('pcm_bname', 'LIKE', "%Social%")
             ->get();
          return view('processspj.adtranspc',[
                   'writter' => $writter,
                   'processmaster' => $processmaster
         ]};


      *This is my view (this error here)
       <table id="table2" class="table table-hover table-striped">
          <tr>
             <th scope="col"></th>
             <th scope="col">Colname1</th>
          </tr>
           @foreach ($processmaster as $item)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $item['pcm_id'] }}</td>
              <td>{{ $item['pcm_bname'] }}</td>
            </tr>
           @endforeach
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my controller
public function adtranspc(Request $request)
    {
      $writter = Writter::all();
         $processmaster = DB::table('rocessmaster')
         ->where('pcm_bname', 'LIKE', "%Social%")
         ->get();

      return view('processspj.adtranspc',[
               'writter' => $writter,
               'processmaster' => $processmaster
     ]};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print your `object` values as an `array`.You need to update your code with this, access your object values like this way

```
 @foreach ($processmaster as $item)
   <tr>
    <td>{{ $item->pcm_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->pcm_bname }}</td>
   </tr>
 @endforeac
```